# How can I make the width of my <figcaption> match the width of the <img> inside its <figure> tag?

Tags: css, html

Say, I got this code:

```
<figure>
 <img src="bunnyrabbit.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="An image of a bunny rabbit." />
 <figcaption>Bunny rabits are cuddly and fluffy creatures with big ears. They eat carrots.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

If I don't use any CSS the figcaption will expand the width of the figure element beyond 200px. How can I prevent this?

I know I can force the text inside the figcaption to wrap by specifying the width of the figure element (`<figure style="width:200px;">`) but I don't really want to use this for each and every image.

Comment: That’s a very good question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks. To expand a bit on the issue, what I'm trying to do is float a figcaption to the right of an image:

`figure {
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid #333;
}
figure img {
 float: left;
}
figcaption {
 float: left;
 padding: 4px;
}`

If the text inside the figcaption is too long the element is wrapped underneath the image. Same issue, but in a slightly different way.

Another issue is that when the figcaption is floated the figure element collapses. Is there a CSS alternative for adding a `<br clear />` after the figcaption?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you want the `figcaption` to be the same width as the image, but not under the image?

Comment: ah, so I've actually re-stated the question wrongly, at least as far as your actual issue goes.

Comment: Use `max-content` instead of `min-content`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This will place the `figcaption` side by side with the `img`:

```
figure {
    display: table;
}
img, figcaption {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
figcaption {
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/rHV2D/).  However I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve - you say in the question that you want the `figure` to stay at 200px width, but then you comment that you want the `figcaption` to appear to the right, which would make the `figure` wider.  If all you want is for the `figcaption` to be restricted to the width of the image, [this should work](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/rHV2D/1/):

```
figure {
    display: table;
    width: 1px; /* This can be any width, so long as it's narrower than any image */
}
img, figcaption {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, that's sorted. Apologies for the confusion about my comment, I got a bit carried away and realise the two issues are quite different (though both are solved with display:table / table-cell / table-row).

Comment: There may be problems with this approach - when I use it my images disappear on IE.

Comment: @AndFinally What version of IE?

Comment: robertc, think it was ie7, ie8 modes of ie9 as well as ie9. I've since found this simpler css works for all except ie7. I'm probably going to have to size the figure to the image width with jquery for that browser.

figure
{
 display: table;
 width: 100px;
}

.ie7 figure
{
 display: block;
 width: auto;
}

Comment: @AndFinally OK, thanks - mostly I use Linux so I can't test stuff in IE.  Since it seems to work in every other browser however, this is probably an IE bug.

Answer (score 69):

Adding this Code to `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` CSS-Attributes helped me with the same problem. Also, it preserves the responsivenes of your images and captions.

```
figure { display: table; }


figcaption { display: table-caption; caption-side: bottom ; }
```

1. Adding `display: table;` sets the stage.
2. Adding `display: table-caption;` alone placed the caption on top of
   the image,  The `caption-side` property specifies the placement of
   the table caption at the `bottom`, `top` is default.

Comment: I like that. And once you remove the width and height from the HTML, you can make the image responsive by adding `figure img { width: 100%}` to Marco's solution or robertc's second solution (table-row).

Comment: Thanks. This one worked for me. The most popular solution messed up with a treescript (which used tables) I had going, which I could fix, but then I noticed it messed up things on an iPhone 4 (don't know about any other phones), which I didn't know how to fix. But this solution had no issues with anything.

Comment: I couldn't get this solution working responsively with either `figure img { width: 100%}`  nor with `img { max-width: 100%; height: auto !important; }`  nor a combination of both http://jsfiddle.net/jwilson3/9y13rsgy/

Comment: Marco's suggestion is genius.  I've read around the web, and tried many strategies and variants.  So many mechanisms for alignment, for so many use cases, but odd that this was the first mention of a simple, standardized solution that "just worked."  Odd, for what seems like it would be a relatively common need; or maybe not?   (I needed to center an image in the viewport, both vertically and horizontally, with a caption below it, responsive across all screens)  At any rate, thanks man!

Comment: Thanks.  One can also use `display: inline-table` to put a row of figures across the screen.

Answer (score 26):

### Another solution: Use [Intrinsic width](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing-3/#intrinsic)

Just set `width: min-content;` on the `figure` element

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/x20vc1n4/2/)** (Except for IE)

```css
figure {
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src=" http://placehold.it/200x150" width="200" height="150" alt="An image of a bunny rabbit." />
  <figcaption>Bunny rabits are cuddly and fluffy creatures with big ears. They eat carrots.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**NB:** [Browser Support is OK](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width), except for IE, however [they are considering implementing this](https://status.modern.ie/cssintrinsicsizing)

Comment: This should be the first answer. It's the most elegant and correct solution, and with Modernizr it's easy enough to solve the problem differently in IE.

Comment: This is almost a perfect solution, except that it doesn't work at all with responsive images. All you need to do to see this break is add`img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}` to the demo fiddle, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jwilson3/ta17f9Lh/

Comment: @JamesWilson This can be fixed using something like `figure { max-width: 100%; } figure > img { max-width: none; }`.

Comment: @Archagon Not sure how that helps. It causes the image to stop being responsive... http://jsfiddle.net/jwilson3/Lhrjew6v/  Would appreciate a working example.

Comment: But will this shrink the image too if the caption is narrower?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, setting the width of the figure instead of using `max-width: 100%` means that it won't shrink on narrow (mobile) devices. That is, the images will not be [responsive](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/). I resorted to inserting `<br />` to break up long captions, but I didn't like it. But this obscure CSS feature seems to work for me:

`figcaption {
display: run-in;
width: 150px
}`

This keeps the image responsive, even though the caption isn't. You can pick your own caption width. I also added `margin: auto;
text-align: center;` to center the caption on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

This was really bothering me, because I wanted to find an answer to accommodate an upgrade to HTML5 that would successfully replace my original setup of displaying images and captions- a table with two rows (or one if no caption was available).

My solution might not work for everyone, but so far, it seems to do just fine in the major browsers (O, FF, IE, S, C), as well as being responsive on mobile devices:

```
figure {
border: 0px solid #000;
display: table;
width: 0;
}
```

The idea here is that `figure` is pushed into existence by the width of the `img` and so doesn't need any kind of direction.

```
figure img {
display: block;
}
```

This is used to rid ourselves of the useless, unsightly gap between the bottom of `img` and the bottom of `figure`.

```
figcaption {
text-align: left;
}
```

Now that figure has been pushed open just wide enough to let `img` in, `figcaption` text has only that limited amount of space in which to exist. `text-align` is not required for this solution to function.

This solution works as well as `display: table-caption`, but keeps `figcaption` contained in any border or background value that might need to be set.

Answer (score 1):

```
figure {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

figcaption {
    width: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

demo: https://codepen.io/kartofelek007/pen/rNZWpjp

you may also use this technique for height:
https://codepen.io/kartofelek007/pen/LYQJJPR

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using display inline-table and display table-caption (include the box-sizing) ... https://codepen.io/keith-purtell/pen/LYMWWPd

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Adapted from Mihovil Ilakovac</h3>
  <h3>With <code>display:inline-table</code></h3>
  <p>Just when you thought all the table nonsense was gone.</p>
 <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"
         alt="Amazing really"
  <figcaption>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.     </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

```
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Be sure to include this! */
}
.container { 
  width:960px;
  margin:10px auto;  
}
figure {
  display: inline-table;
  margin: 1em 0 1.3em 0;
  padding: 0em;
  position: relative;
  width: 66%;   
  }  
img {
 display:block;
    }
figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0.7em auto;
  text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a descriptive answer and then references,

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34937110)

Comment: Sachith and Ben, edited today.