# Background color width of <figcaption> works fine in Chrome, but does not display properly in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I had started experimenting with webdev after long break and can not figure our why the Figcaption is not displayed properly in Safari.

I had created the website www.suezre.com and when viewed in Chrome or Firefox figcaption on the pictures looks good, but on Safari it takes much more space.

Any suggestion how i could fix this?

Thank you 
R

```
<figure>
  <img src="../img/budapest_our_home_city.png"/>
  <figcaption>Budapest, our home city</figcaption>
</figure>
```

```
figure {
position: relative;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding:  15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba( 29, 20, 17, .6);
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.banner img {
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Adding to [the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534473/how-can-i-make-the-width-of-my-figcaption-match-the-width-of-the-img-inside) to a similar question, here.)

I added `display: table` and `margin: auto` to `figure`, and `display: table-caption` to `figcaption`. Seemed to work fine on both after that.

Comment: Hi Toby, thank you very much for this, i did try to display it in block and inline block, but not table. It does solve the issue! Thank you very much, will make a note of this for future!

Comment: Awesome. Learned something, myself. ;D